# How do I remove all the selected items in a QListWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

QListWidget::selectedItems returns a list of QListWidgetItem, but the only function for removing an item that I found is takeItem, which accepts only indexes, and selectedIndexes function is protected.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try

```
qDeleteAll(listWidget->selectedItems());
```

Comment: This seems to work, but from the help it seems qDeleteAll is just a generic function that calls delete on a range of objects. Won't the QListWidget still think it has those items?

Comment: I found [this link](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2007-09/thread00253-0.html) that explains why it works - a QListWidgetItem's destructor removes it from the QListWidget. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Iterate through the SelectedItemsList:

```
QList<QListWidgetItem *> itemList = widget->selectedItems();
for (int i=0; i<itemList.size(); i++) {
     widget->takeItem(widget->indexFromItem(itemList[i]));
}
```

I think

```
widget->removeItemWidget(itemList[i]);
```

may also work

Comment: From the Qt `takeItem` documentation: "Items removed from a list widget will not be managed by Qt, and will need to be deleted manually." So you should say `delete widget->takeItem(...);`

Answer (score 0):

ui->listWidget->clear();
will do asof qt5

Comment: can you explain please?

Comment: ui->listWidget->clear(); will clear all the previous entries in the list widget

Comment: In Qt5 QListWidget::clear() method properly works for the purpose of this question as @dravigon says :-)